# Can you find a ellipse so that its image is a circle?

Tags: 3d

This is a "fun" question and I have already a solution. I asked this question so that I may see a different approach or an elegant solution.

Let $P$ be a plane with equation $x+y+z=1$. Find an ellipse on $x,y$ plane so that its "shadow" on $P$ is a circle.

**Edit:** By "shadow", I mean $(x,y)\to(x,y,z)$ where $(x,y,z)\in P$

Comment: Does "shadow" mean it's *orthogonal* projection to $P$? Or any projection?

Comment: $(x,y)\to (x,y,z)$ where $(x,y,z)\in P$

Comment: Have you tried to reverse engineer this? Take a circle on P, and let the ellipse be its "pre-shadow" on the $xy$-plane. For example the circle via the points $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$. That circle lies on the cylinder $$\Vert(x,y,z)-\frac{x+y+z}3(1,1,1)\Vert^2=\frac23.$$

Comment: @mesel Yes, but what are the *constraints* on this transform $F$? You can, for example, find a *rotation+translation* that maps the $xy$-plane into $P$, and the problem is trivial then, since rotations and translations map circles to circles. But that's quite certainly not what you want. The minimal requirement you probably want to impose is probably that $F$ is *idempotent*, meaning that applying it twice is the same as applying it once. That makes $F$ a *projection*. But there are still many such projections (because you can *pick* the direction the light comes from)...

Comment: @mesel Ah, OK, I think I see what you want. You want a projection onto $P$ in the $z$-direction, i.e. You map $(x,y,0)$ to $(x,y,1-x-y)$, right?

Comment: @fgp:we set $F(x,y)=(x,y,z)$ and $(x,y,z)\in P$ which means $z=1-x-y$ so $F(x,y)=(x,y,1-x-y)$ which uniqly determine the $F$ ?.

Comment: @fgp: now, it is okey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circle with radius 1 and center $(0,0,1)$ in the plane $x+y+z=1$ can be parametrized by
\begin{align}
\vec{p}(t) &= \langle 0,0,1 \rangle + \cos(t)\langle 1,-1,0 \rangle/\sqrt{2} + \sin(t) \langle 1,1,-2 \rangle/\sqrt{6} \\
 &= \left\langle \frac{\sin (t)}{\sqrt{6}}+\frac{\cos
   (t)}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{\sin (t)}{\sqrt{6}}-\frac{\cos
   (t)}{\sqrt{2}},1-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \sin (t) \right\rangle.
 \end{align}
It's shadow can be parametrized by just dropping the $z$ coordinate.
$$\vec{s}(t) = \left\langle \frac{\sin (t)}{\sqrt{6}}+\frac{\cos
   (t)}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{\sin (t)}{\sqrt{6}}-\frac{\cos
   (t)}{\sqrt{2}} \right\rangle.$$

This is enough to visualize.

[image]

Once we have the parametrization, we can generate points on the ellipse by simply plugging in $t$ values.  Here are five points on the ellipse in the plane, for example.

$$
\begin{array}{l|l}
 t & (x,y) \\
\hline
 0 & \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \\
\hline
 \frac{\pi }{3} & \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0\right) \\
\hline
 \frac{\pi }{2} & \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\right) \
\\
\hline
 \pi  & \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \\
\hline
 \frac{3 \pi }{2} & \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\right)
\end{array}
$$

Since five points determine an ellipse, we can find the Cartesian formula easily enough.  My favorite technique is to set the following determinant equal to zero.

$$
\left|
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 x^2 & x y & y^2 & x & y & 1 \\
 \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} &
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 1 \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & 1 \\
 \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} &
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & 1 \\
 \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} &
   -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 1 \\
 \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} &
   -\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right|
$$

After some simplification, this yields 
$$
2 x^2 + 2 xy + 2 y^2 = 1.
$$

Comment: even if it is long, it is a nice solution. I did not know the method "determinant".

Comment: @mesel Thanks! I suppose it's "long", if your ultimate objective is the Cartesian formula. It seems quite direct to get to the parametric description, though. :)

Comment: Your figure is also nice :)

Comment: Check my solution, you will see why I said "long" :)

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, I'll use the plane $x + y + z = 0$ instead of $x + y + z = 1$.

Suppose the circle on the plane $x + y + z = 0$ is a unit circle centered at $(0, 0, 0)$. It intersects the $xy$-plane at $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(-1, 1, 0)$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(1, -1, 0)$.
It intersects the plane $x = y$ at $\frac 1{\sqrt 6}(1, 1, -2)$ and $\frac 1{\sqrt 6}(-1, -1, 2)$. These four points, projected onto the $xy$-plane, define the major and minor axes of the ellipse on the $xy$-plane. (In particular, the major and minor axes have length $2$ and $\frac 2{\sqrt{3}}$, and they make $\pi/4$ angle with the standard $xy$-axis.)

Answer (score 0):

Let $C$ be the unit circle on the plane $P$ centered at $R=(0,0,1)\in P$ and $(x_0,y_0)$ be 
projection of any point of $C$  to $x,y$ plane.

Then $T=(x_0,y_0,1-x_0-y_0)\in C$ and by constraction $d(R,T)=1.$
So, $$|(x_0,y_0,-x_0-y_0)|=1$$
$$x_0^2+y_0^2+x_0^2+2x_0y_0+y_0^2=1$$
$$2x_0^2+2y_0^2+2x_0y_0=1$$ Hence, The equation of ellipse is $2x^2+2y^2+2xy=1$